# Intellij IDEA Tomcat git clone web application

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I am trying to git clone in Intellij IDEA for testing purpose @ localhost this GitHub repository: https://github.com/copperhead/AttestationServer

This is an actual working online implementation: https://attestation.copperhead.co/

I believe that the application consist of frontend HTML and javascript along with backend JAVA and sqlite.

How do I get a local copy that is 100% working as the actual working online implementation. So far I can only run the frontend web logic without the backend java services via localhost. New to intellij here.

See the pic below for the problem I get:

[image: Problem]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I removed the image link and added an image tag and adjusted the formatting of the text. Feel free to make more edit to let other users better understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some points you should consider while working Intellij IDEA

- Go to  **Project Structure** and add reference to SQLite Connector in ***Libraries*** tab
- Go to **Debug/Run Configuration** and set up Tomcat as web server (download tomcat and give path)
- Go to **Project Structure** and set up Artifacts for your web app

**Note:** Before all these step you need to configure you Gradle-wrapper

[Tomcat Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbLmM.png)

Hope so this will help.

Comment: i think i am near! EAR or WAR under artifact? Gradle-wrapper configure what?

Comment: unzip gradle if available otherwise you've to download first then apply.

Comment: i am getting "$END$" in localhot 8080

Comment: Did you see the image to configure Tomcat in the answer?

Comment: Working fine for me.

Comment: yes i did see the image. I am using tomcat v9 though.. after setting tomcat directory, i then proceed to set artifact WAR. Running localhost8080 is giving me "$END$" with a white screen

Comment: "Go to Project Structure and add reference to SQLite Connector in Libraries tab" There is no SQLite connector choice for me. I can only select "Java"

Comment: This is because you didn't set the start page.

Comment: Can i see the image for your Project Structure > Library Tab? I am using WAR btw. Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: how do i get the start page?

Comment: SQLite connector is java based jar file so download from intellij IDEA repository or from Google.

Comment: e.g. Localhost:8080/index

Comment: currently 404 not found. let me go download SQLite  (SQLScout (SQLite Support) from intelliJ. Thank you so much BTW

Comment: You can configure sqlite through databases->data source->sqlite->Install Missing driver

Comment: i added SQLScout already. Library dont have the option for me to select SQLite connector: https://imgur.com/a/ug4LWC0

Comment: sqlite(Xerial) is better

Comment: okay i installed and selected sqlite Xerial. Do i still have to select it in Project structure > Library> ? Because there is no option as show in imgur.com/a/ug4LWC0

Comment: i got the web running already. Backend logic not working. Is JavaEEApp not pointing to the .java files properly?

Comment: i can access the web. But i cant create an account upon filling in username and password. What do i need to setup here for the backend java part? > https://imgur.com/a/wKvusXs